# joi nested validation with custom method

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I have a form where if the email field is optional. But, if the value is given then that must be a valid one.

```js
export default async (req, res, next) => {
    const validations = joi.object({
        ...
        email: joi.any().custom((value, helper) => {
            ...

            return joi.object({
                email: joi.string().email(),
            }).validate();

            // ---- OR ----
            return joi.string().email();
        }),
        ...
    });

    const { error } = validations.validate({
        email: 'valid/invalid email address'
    });

    if (error) {
        return res.status(406).send({ ... });
    }

    next();
}
```

Is this even possible, following this way..?